# Combining uneven numbers of plots with a for loop and grid.arrange

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I have hundreds of plots of that I have made with a previous for loop that are named in a consistent manner. The plots are the results of several **tasks** nested within **domains**.

I would like to use grid.arrange to plot all of the tasks of a defined domain on the same plot.

Dummy data that explains the structure of my data and plots:

```
domain_key <- data.frame(domain = c("soe", "soe", "soe", "elit", "elit"), 
                     tasks = c("personal", "size", "shapeid", "onetoone", "puzzle"))

dummy <- ggplot(data.frame()) + geom_point() + xlim(0, 10) + ylim(0, 100)

plot.personalpct <- dummy + ggtitle("plot.personalpct")
plot.sizepct <- dummy  + ggtitle("plot.sizepct")
plot.shapeidpct <- dummy  + ggtitle("plot.shapeidpct")
plot.onetoonepct <- dummy  + ggtitle("plot.onetoonepct")
plot.puzzlepct <- dummy  + ggtitle("plot.puzzlepct")
```

And here is my basic idea of how to do it:

```
for(j in domain_key$domain){
  tasks <- unique(with(domain_key, tasks[domain == j])) #Get a list of the unique tasks for the domain
  plots <- paste("plot.", tasks, "pct", sep ="") #Get the name of the plots as a character vector
  grid.arrange(eval(parse(text = plots))) #evaluate the expression with grid arrange to display all the plots
}
```

My problem is that the final argument only displays the first plot of each domain. This is because my character vector doesn't parse as mulitple objects, probably because they are not separated by a comma. I've tried a bunch of workarounds, but can't figure out a way around this. Or maybe my approach is totally off.

Much appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Maybe just do `grid.arrange(grobs = mget(ls(pattern = "plot\\..*pct")))`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think that will take **all** of my grobs (that begin with "plot" and end with "pct" and put them on one plot. I am looking for a way to make several plots that each contain the grobs associated with a **domain** as specified in my key.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

dummy_plot <- function(id, fill) ggplot() + ggtitle(id) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = fill))

pl = list(`domain 1` = lapply(1:3, dummy_plot, fill = "#FBB4AE"),
          `domain 2` = lapply(1:2, dummy_plot, fill = "#B3CDE3"),
          `domain 3` = lapply(1:4, dummy_plot, fill = "#CCEBC5"),
          `domain 4` = lapply(1:5, dummy_plot, fill = "#DECBE4"))

dummy_group <- function(domain) arrangeGrob(grobs = pl[[domain]], top = domain)
grid.arrange(grobs = lapply(names(pl), dummy_group))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help of @baptiste and @lukeA. Both of their suggestions didn't quite answer my question, but helped put me on the right path.

I realized that I really needed to feed grid.arrange a list, so I found a reasonable, but not terribly elegant solution. I embedded the **domain** name in the plot name for each **task**. Then I fed grid.arrage and list of plots using grep with the domain name. This works reasonably well.

This has a bit too much detail but illustrates my solution:

```
### Graph means of tasks by treatment group with error bars

pltList <- list() #Create and empty list to store task plots

for(outcome in unique(domain_key$task) ){
  df <- data.frame(Intervention.Group = factor(unique(children$treatment)), 
                 Percent.Correct = eval(parse(text = paste0("meansbytreatment$", outcome, "$estimates"))),
                 SE = eval(parse(text = paste0("meansbytreatment$", outcome, "$se")))) 
  df$upper <- df$Percent.Correct + 2*df$SE
  df$lower <- df$Percent.Correct - 2*df$SE #Make a temp df with with the estimates and errors for each treatment group

  domain <- unique( domain_key$domain[domain_key$task == outcome] ) #extract the domain that the task belongs to
  pltName <- paste( "plot", outcome, domain, sep = "." ) #Make a unique plot name with task and domain

  pltList[[ pltName ]] <- ggplot(df, aes(Intervention.Group, Percent.Correct, fill = Intervention.Group)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), width = 0.4) +
    ggtitle(paste(outcome, "by Intervention Group") )+ 
    theme(legend.position="none") #Save the plot to the plot list 
}

### Graph domain subtasks together

Domainplt <- lst() #Make an empty list to store plots of all the taks in a domain

for(j in unique(domain_key$domain)){
  plots <- grep(j, names(pltList)) #get all of the plots from the domain
  nplots <- length(plots) # get the n of plots for the domain
  Domainplt[[j]] <- grid.arrange(grobs = pltList[plots],
                                 ncol = nplots,
                                 top =  j) #Arrange all of the plots horizontally
}
```